# EPSON OPOS ADK for .NET VB.NET Printer Sample Program throws Exception: "The printer is currently being initialized."

Tags: .net, vb.net, printing, epson, pos-for-.net

I am currently trying out the VB.NET PrinterSample_Step1, "Hello OPOS for .Net" . I have installed the driver for TM-H6000IV using EPSON advanced driver and set it up in the SetUpPOS for OPOS.NET .
When I run the sample program, it will return the exception: `{"The printer is currently being initialized."}`. When I run the CheckHealthTest ,it will be stuck on this screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNh0C.jpg and it will return this error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFbsm.jpg .
This is the code from the sample program:

```
Imports Microsoft.PointOfService


Public Class FrameStep1
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    Private m_Printer As Microsoft.PointOfService.PosPrinter = Nothing


#Region " Windows Forms Designer generated code."

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()

        ' The InitializeComponent() call is required for windows Forms designer support.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' TODO: Add counstructor code after the InitializeComponent() call.

    End Sub

    ' Rear treatment is carried out in the resource being used.
    Protected Overloads Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        If disposing Then
            If Not (components Is Nothing) Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        End If
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    End Sub

    ' Design  variable.
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    ' This method is required for Windows Forms designer support.
    'Do not change the method contents inside the source code editor.   
    ' The Forms designer might not be able to load this method if it was changed manually.
    Friend WithEvents btnPrint As System.Windows.Forms.Button
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Me.btnPrint = New System.Windows.Forms.Button
        Me.SuspendLayout()
        '
        'btnPrint
        '
        Me.btnPrint.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(84, 40)
        Me.btnPrint.Name = "btnPrint"
        Me.btnPrint.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(120, 32)
        Me.btnPrint.TabIndex = 0
        Me.btnPrint.Text = "Print"
        '
        'FrameStep1
        '
        Me.AutoScaleBaseSize = New System.Drawing.Size(5, 12)
        Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(280, 125)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.btnPrint)
        Me.MaximizeBox = False
        Me.Name = "FrameStep1"
        Me.Text = "Step1 Print ""Hello OPOS for .Net"""
        Me.ResumeLayout(False)

    End Sub

#End Region

    ''' <summary>
    '''  A method "Print" calls some another method.
    '''  They are method for printing.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="sender"></param>
    ''' <param name="e"></param>
    Private Sub btnPrint_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object _
    , ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPrint.Click

        '<<<step1>>> Start
        Try
            'As using the PrintNormal method, send strings to a printer, and print it
            '[vbCrLf] is the standard code for starting a new line.
            m_Printer.PrintNormal(PrinterStation.Receipt, "Hello OPOS for .Net" + vbCrLf)

        Catch ex As PosControlException

        End Try
        '<<<step2>>> End

    End Sub
    ''' <summary>
    ''' When the method "changeButtonStatus" was called,
    ''' all buttons other than a button "closing" become invalid.
    ''' </summary>
    Private Sub ChangeButtonStatus()

        'Disable control.
        btnPrint.Enabled = False
    End Sub
    ''' <summary>
    ''' The processing code required in order to enable to use of service is written here.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="sender"></param>
    ''' <param name="e"></param>
    Private Sub FrameStep1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object _
    , ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        '<<<step1>>>--Start
        'Use a Logical Device Name which has been set on the SetupPOS.
        Dim strLogicalName As String
        Dim deviceInfo As DeviceInfo
        Dim posExplorer As PosExplorer

        strLogicalName = "PosPrinter2"

        'Create PosExplorer
        posExplorer = New PosExplorer

        m_Printer = Nothing

        Try

            deviceInfo = posExplorer.GetDevice(DeviceType.PosPrinter, strLogicalName)
            m_Printer = posExplorer.CreateInstance(deviceInfo)

        Catch ex As Exception
            ChangeButtonStatus()
            Return
        End Try

        Try

            'Open the device
            m_Printer.Open()

            'Get the exclusive control right for the opened device.
            'Then the device is disable from other application.
            m_Printer.Claim(1000)

            'Enable the device.
            m_Printer.DeviceEnabled = True

        Catch ex As PosControlException

            ChangeButtonStatus()

        End Try
        '<<<step1>>>--End
    End Sub
    ''' <summary>
    ''' When the method "closing" is called,
    ''' the following code is run.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="sender"></param>
    ''' <param name="e"></param>
    Private Sub FrameStep1_Closing(ByVal sender As Object _
    , ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Closing

        '<<<step1>>>--Start
        If m_Printer Is Nothing Then
            Return
        End If

        Try
            'Cancel the device
            m_Printer.DeviceEnabled = False

            'Release the device exclusive control right.
            m_Printer.Release()


        Catch ex As Exception

        Finally
            'Finish using the device.
            m_Printer.Close()

        End Try
        '<<<step1>>>--End

    End Sub
End Class
```

The exception will be caught here in these lines:

```
    Private Sub btnPrint_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object _
    , ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPrint.Click

        '<<<step1>>> Start
        Try
            'As using the PrintNormal method, send strings to a printer, and print it
            '[vbCrLf] is the standard code for starting a new line.
            m_Printer.PrintNormal(PrinterStation.Receipt, "Hello OPOS for .Net" + vbCrLf)

        Catch ex As PosControlException

        End Try
        '<<<step2>>> End

    End Sub
```

I have found this Q&A: https://okbizcs.okwave.jp/epson/questiondetail/?qid=8318452 but it does not seem to be relevant to this issue.

This is the full exception from CheckHealthTest:

```
================== Exception =====================
Microsoft.PointOfService.PosControlException
ErrorCode : Offline (108)
ErrorCodeExtended : 5010
Message : The printer is currently being initialized.
Target : System.String CheckHealth(Microsoft.PointOfService.HealthCheckLevel)
## StackTrace ##
   at jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_14_0001.pntr.CommonPrinterService.CheckHealth(HealthCheckLevel level)
   at CheckHealthTest.MainForm.ExecuteCheckHealth(DeviceInfo objInfo)
   at CheckHealthTest.MainForm.btnCheckHealth_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
---------InnerException-----------
jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_14_0001.pntr.state.PrinterStateException
Message : The printer is currently being initialized.
Target : Void ConfirmConditionForNotOfflineCommand(Int32)
## StackTrace ##
   at jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_14_0001.pntr.state.PrinterState_USBSerialCompatible.ConfirmConditionForNotOfflineCommand(Int32 iStation)
   at jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_14_0001.pntr.io.CommonOutputToPrinterAndEJ.CheckError(Int32[] aiStationIndex, Boolean bAfterQueue)
```

This is the stack trace from the program:

```
ErrorCode: Failure
ErrorCodeExtended: 0
Stack trace:    at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
   at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
   at Microsoft.PointOfService.PosException.GetExceptionText(Exception e)
   at Microsoft.PointOfService.PosException.LogError()
   at Microsoft.PointOfService.PosControlException..ctor(String message, ErrorCode errorCode, Int32 errorCodeExtended)
   at jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_14_0001.pntr.init.AbstractPrinterInitialization.OutputData(Byte[] abyData, Boolean bAddSelect, Int64 lTimeout, Boolean bFlow)
   at jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_14_0001.pntr.init.AbstractPrinterInitialization.OutputData(Byte[] abyData, Boolean bFlow)
   at jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_14_0001.pntr.init.AbstractPrinterInitialization.GetPrinterStatus(Boolean bFullCheck, Int64 lTimeout)
   at jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_14_0001.pntr.init.AbstractPrinterInitialization.GetPrinterStatus(Boolean bFullCheck)
   at jp.co.epson.upos.H6000IV.pntr.init.H6000IV_Initialization.InitializeCommon()
   at jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_14_0001.pntr.init.AbstractPrinterInitialization.Initialize()
   at jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_14_0001.pntr.init.AbstractPrinterInitialization.Initialize(Int32 iResetCounter)
   at jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_14_0001.pntr.init.InitializationThread.ThreadProcess()
   at jp.co.epson.uposcommon.core.v1_14_0001.util.EpsonCommonThread.Run()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
[PosException]: Microsoft.PointOfService.PosControlException: The device is offline.
ErrorCode: Failure
ErrorCodeExtended: 0
Stack trace:    at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
   at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
   at Microsoft.PointOfService.PosException.GetExceptionText(Exception e)
   at Microsoft.PointOfService.PosException.LogError()
   at Microsoft.PointOfService.PosControlException..ctor(String message, ErrorCode errorCode, Int32 errorCodeExtended)
   at jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_14_0001.pntr.init.AbstractPrinterInitialization.OutputData(Byte[] abyData, Boolean bAddSelect, Int64 lTimeout, Boolean bFlow)
   at jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_14_0001.pntr.init.AbstractPrinterInitialization.GetRealtimeStatus()
   at jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_14_0001.pntr.init.AbstractPrinterInitialization.GetPrinterStatus(Boolean bFullCheck, Int64 lTimeout)
   at jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_14_0001.pntr.init.AbstractPrinterInitialization.GetPrinterStatus(Boolean bFullCheck)
   at jp.co.epson.upos.H6000IV.pntr.init.H6000IV_Initialization.InitializeCommon()
   at jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_14_0001.pntr.init.AbstractPrinterInitialization.Initialize()
   at jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_14_0001.pntr.init.AbstractPrinterInitialization.Initialize(Int32 iResetCounter)
   at jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_14_0001.pntr.init.InitializationThread.ThreadProcess()
   at jp.co.epson.uposcommon.core.v1_14_0001.util.EpsonCommonThread.Run()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
[PosException]: Microsoft.PointOfService.PosControlException: The printer is currently being initialized. ---> jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_14_0001.pntr.state.PrinterStateException: The printer is currently being initialized.
   at jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_14_0001.pntr.state.PrinterState_USBSerialCompatible.ConfirmConditionForNotOfflineCommand(Int32 iStation)
   at jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_14_0001.pntr.state.PrinterState_USBSerialCompatible.ConfirmCondition(Int32 iStation)
   at jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_14_0001.pntr.io.CommonOutputToPrinterAndEJ.CheckError(Int32[] aiStationIndex, Boolean bAfterQueue)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
ErrorCode: Failure
ErrorCodeExtended: 0
Stack trace:    at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
   at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
   at Microsoft.PointOfService.PosException.GetExceptionText(Exception e)
   at Microsoft.PointOfService.PosException.LogError()
   at jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_14_0001.pntr.CommonUPOSExceptionCreator.CreatePosControlException(Int32 iErrorCode, Int32 iErrorCodeExtended, String strMessage, Exception orgException)
   at jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_14_0001.pntr.CommonUPOSExceptionCreator.CreatePosControlException(PrinterStateException orgException, Boolean bAfterQueue)
   at jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_14_0001.pntr.io.CommonOutputToPrinterAndEJ.CheckError(Int32[] aiStationIndex, Boolean bAfterQueue)
   at jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_14_0001.pntr.io.CommonOutputToPrinterAndEJ.OutputToPrinterImp(OutputDataStruct dataStruct, Boolean fromPrinterService)
   at jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_14_0001.pntr.io.CommonOutputToPrinterAndEJ.OutputToPrinter(OutputDataStruct dataStruct)
   at jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_14_0001.pntr.io.OutputToPrinterForProcessID_EJ.OutputToPrinter(OutputDataStruct dataStruct)
   at jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_14_0001.pntr.CommonPrinterService.SendOutputData(OutputDataStruct outputData, Int32 iTransmitType, Boolean bAsync, Boolean bFlow, Boolean bImmediate)
   at jp.co.epson.upos.H6000IV.pntr.H6000IVService.SendOutputData(OutputDataStruct outputData, Int32 iTransmitType, Boolean bAsync, Boolean bFlow, Boolean bImmediate)
   at jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_14_0001.pntr.CommonPrinterService.SendOutputData(OutputDataStruct outputData, Boolean bAsync, Boolean bFlow, Boolean bImmediate)
   at jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_14_0001.pntr.CommonPrinterService.ExecuteNormalPrint(Int32 iStationIndex, String strData, Boolean bTransaction, Boolean bFlow, Boolean bImmediate)
   at jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_14_0001.pntr.CommonPrinterService.PrintNormal(PrinterStation station, String strData)
   at jp.co.epson.upos.H6000IV.pntr.H6000IVService.PrintNormal(PrinterStation station, String strData)
   at PrinterSample_Step1.FrameStep1.btnPrint_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Epson-OPOS-ADK\Samples\VB.NET\Printer\PrinterSample_Step1\FrameStep1.vb:line 78
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at PrinterSample_Step1.FrameStep1.Main()
Inner Exception: jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_14_0001.pntr.state.PrinterStateException: The printer is currently being initialized.
   at jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_14_0001.pntr.state.PrinterState_USBSerialCompatible.ConfirmConditionForNotOfflineCommand(Int32 iStation)
   at jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_14_0001.pntr.state.PrinterState_USBSerialCompatible.ConfirmCondition(Int32 iStation)
   at jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_14_0001.pntr.io.CommonOutputToPrinterAndEJ.CheckError(Int32[] aiStationIndex, Boolean bAfterQueue)
Stack trace:    at jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_14_0001.pntr.state.PrinterState_USBSerialCompatible.ConfirmConditionForNotOfflineCommand(Int32 iStation)
   at jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_14_0001.pntr.state.PrinterState_USBSerialCompatible.ConfirmCondition(Int32 iStation)
   at jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_14_0001.pntr.io.CommonOutputToPrinterAndEJ.CheckError(Int32[] aiStationIndex, Boolean bAfterQueue)
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.PointOfService.PosControlException' in Epson.opos.tm.service.v1_14_0001.dll
The program '[16316] PrinterSample_Step1.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here.  The call stack for that exception looks to be coming from the MainForm.btnCheckHealth_Click event handler.  I'm not seeing that or the ExecuteCheckHealth in your attached code.

Comment: Hi, that exception is from https://imgur.com/avz0wyz. 
Edit: I have added the stack trace from the attached code.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the printer's receipt roll is not properly loaded or the paper/printhead cover is open.

In that state, normal commands cannot be sent to the printer, so printing cannot be performed.

Since the Claim method and the initialization when DeviceEnabled=true is set and the status notification specification command cannot be sent, it may have been determined that the printer is still in the initialization process and cannot communicate.

If the receipt roll or printer cover is in good condition, but you still get those errors, then you have either specified the COM port name you are connecting to, or the printer and device drivers are not in serial port mode(vendor class). It may be set to parallel port mode(printer class).

It is probably the result of those that have been notified of the error.

---

**In response to the comment description:**

If you don't have a printer connected, that's all.
The sample program assumes that an actual printer that can print in a normal state is connected.

It is not limited to EPSON printers, but any printer or other devices.
Unless explicitly provided with simulator/emulator software.

Comment: Hi, I am currently testing with the drivers only as I do not have the physical printers. The printers status are "Status : Unavailable".

Comment: Thank you for the reply, so just to clarify, the only way the ADK sample programs would run is if an Epson printer is connected? I did connect a non-Epson printer and set the driver as the Epson driver, but it does not work.

Comment: To run the sample program and get successful results, the appropriate printer must be connected properly.